# C# Var vs Target-typed new

Tags: c#, var, variable-declaration

C#9 was [officially announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/) a couple days ago. One new language features is "target-typed new expressions", which feel pretty similar in usage to `var`. Comparing the following declarations, I'm curious which is more performant, if any, and which syntax should be preferred for different contexts.

`var person = new Person()` vs `Person person = new()`.

And for collections:

```cs
var people = new[] {
    new Person(),
    new Person(),
    new Person(),
}
```

vs

```cs
var people = new Person[] {
    new(),
    new(),
    new(),
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by performance, its a compiler feature, does not have any runtime implications

Comment: I doubt there's any real difference in terms of the IL generated

Comment: @MatJ Everything I found online about `var` was comparing it to explicitly-typed declarations, or requesting that it be allowed on member declarations. This C#9 syntax is quite new, so I figured I'd ask the question. I also don't know everything about how compilers work, so I didnt know if it had runtime implications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var person = new Person()` and `Person person = new()` will compile to the same IL code. They are just 2 different ways to tell the compiler which type to initialize; they do not have anything to do with runtime performance.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgi! I didnt know if there was any difference in the IL generated. I think I'm personally liking `var` for single variables cause then all declarations can line up on the left, and target-typed `new` for collections so there's less repetition.

Comment: Target typed new is especially useful for class-level fields that include generics. Like `private readonly Dictionary<string, SomeLongTypeName> _dict = new Dictionary<string, SomeLongTypeName>();` versus `private readonly Dictionary<string, SomeLongTypeName> _dict = new();`